# change css of the div which come after parent div

Tags: jquery, html

Hello I want to add class to the span of the div which come after parent div.

**HTML**

```
<div class="stepwizard">
    <ul class="stepwizard-row">
        <li class="stepwizard-step">
            <span class="step-border"><a href="#step1" class="data-toggle="tab">1</a></span>
         //If user  click here <span class="step1"> should be change
        </li>
        <li class="stepwizard-step">
            <span class=""><a href="#step2" data-toggle="tab" >2</a></span>
          //If user  click here <span class="step2"> should be change
        </li>
        <li class="stepwizard-step">
            <span class=""><a href="#step3" class="p-n-t step-tab" aria-controls="documents" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">3</a></span>
       //If user  click here <span class="step3"> should be change
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="m-t-sm step-title">
    <span class="step1">BASIC INFO</span> //here i want to add class
    <span class="step2">REGISTERED NUMBERS</span>
    <span class="step3">CLIENT SERVICES</span>
</div>
```

Here When user click on `<a>` tag i want to add class to `<span>` which come after `<div class="m-t-sm step-title">` .

How to do this using jquery ?

Comment: `$('.m-t-sm.step-title > .step1').css('color', 'red').addClass('yourClass')`

Comment: but it is condition base. if user click on first <a> tag the first span (step1) should be change . In second and third <a> tag step2 and step3 should be change.

Comment: Your question is still not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**used to this**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        $(this).parents('.stepwizard').next().find('span').addClass('yourClass');
    });
});
```

I have updated to my answer `@Rino Raj` take code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        var position = $(this).attr('href').split("#")[1];
        $('.m-t-sm.step-title  span').removeClass('your_class');
        $('.'+position ).addClass('your_class');
        
    });
});
```

```css
.your_class{border:solid 10px red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stepwizard">
    <ul class="stepwizard-row">
        <li class="stepwizard-step">
            <span class="step-border"><a href="#step1">1</a></span>
         
        </li>
        <li class="stepwizard-step">
            <span class=""><a href="#step2">2</a></span>
          
        </li>
        <li class="stepwizard-step">
            <span class=""><a href="#step3">3</a></span>
        
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="m-t-sm step-title">
    <span class="step1">BASIC INFO</span>
    <span class="step2">REGISTERED NUMBERS</span>
    <span class="step3">CLIENT SERVICES</span>
</div>
```

Comment: it is working but.... it is condition base. if user click on first <a> tag the first span (step1) should be change . In second and third <a> tag step2 and step3 should be change

Answer (score 2):

**Please try this**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        var position = $(this).attr('href').split("#")[1];
        $('.'+position ).addClass('your_class')
    });
});
```

Comment: no not working...it is condition base. if user click on first <a> tag the first span (step1) should be change . In second and third <a> tag step2 and step3 should be change

Comment: wow thats great. but then how to remove previously added class to that step1,2,3 ?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest option is to add a direct link between the two, rather than parse the ID to find the class to select.

This also allows you to use symantic names rather than "1", "2" etc.

Add `data-step` to each `a` and a matching `data-step` to each `step-title`

```
<div class="stepwizard">
    <ul class="stepwizard-row">
        <li class="stepwizard-step">
            <span class="step-border">
                <a href="#step1" data-step="step1" data-toggle="tab">1</a>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li class="stepwizard-step">
            <span class="">
                <a href="#step2" data-step="stepnumbers" data-toggle="tab">2</a>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li class="stepwizard-step">
            <span class="">
                <a href="#step3" data-step="laststep" class="p-n-t step-tab" aria-controls="documents" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">3</a>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="m-t-sm step-title">
    <span class="step1" data-step="step1">BASIC INFO</span> //here i want to add class
    <span class="stepnumbers" data-step="step2">REGISTERED NUMBERS</span>
    <span class="laststep" data-step="step3">CLIENT SERVICES</span>
</div>
```

Then it's easy to link the two:

```
$(".stepwizard a[data-step]").click(function() {
    $(".step-title>span").removeClass("selected");
    $(".step-title>span[data-step=" + $(this).data("step") + "]").addClass("selected");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below. Find the closest `.stepwizard` and then `.step1` under the next `div` of it.

```
$("a").click(function () {
    var i = $(this).text().trim()-1;
    $(this).closest('.stepwizard').next('div').find('span').eq(i).addClass('your_class');
});
```

Comment: it is working but.... it is condition base. if user click on first <a> tag the first span (step1) should be change . In second and third <a> tag step2 and step3 should be change